# Size of an 2dim array

Tags: c++, arrays

When I have something like this:

```
int Numbers[] = 
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
}
```

I can simply get size of this array 'int numNumbers = ARRAYSIZE(Numbers);'

And my question is... Will this work for array like this:

```
int Numbers[][2] = 
{
    { 1,2 },
    { 3,4 },
    { 5,6 },
}
```

Comment: Like: http://ideone.com/KtGxEn  `sizeof(Numbers)/sizeof(Numbers[0])` to get the amount of rows.. and `sizeof(Numbers)/sizeof(int)` to get the amount of elements.. Then `number of elements / number of rows` gives `number of columns`.

Comment: ok so for 1dim array it's `ARRAYSIZE(a)`and for multidim arrays it's `_ARRAYSIZE(a)` right?

Comment: I don't know what `ARRAYSIZE` is but I believe it is just a macro that does `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`.. See here: http://ideone.com/Hs6tW6  for alternatives..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this definition of ARRAYSIZE:

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*(a)))
```

This definitely works for both single and two dimensional arrays. `sizeof(a)` is size of array `a` i.e. (number of elements in array) * (size of an element) where `sizeof (*a)` is size of an element.
Similarly for two dimensional case, `sizeof(a)` is number of elements in complete array and `sizeof(*a)` means size of array in one of its dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ARRAYSIZE` is something like:

```
#define ARRAYSIZE(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0]))
```

Then yes, it will, because in the second case `a[0]` is the same as "array of 2 integers", so `sizeof(a[0])` will evaluate to `sizeof(int)*2`.

`ARRAYSIZE()` will always work with arrays of arbitrary dimension, just be careful not to use it inside a function where the array was passed as an argument, since you will not have a real array anymore in that case.